How to get latest version of AutoMapper to flatten complex property paths to destination properties named using "_" as a splitting char by default
I am trying to update an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web project to .NET 8 and have it basically working, but the default behaviour in AutoMapper 13.0.1 is to perform flattening on mapping a complex source by using a PascalCase naming convention.
For example if you named the destination property AccountName, then if the source had a class property called Account, and the Account object had a property called Name, then AccountName would be automatically mapped from Account.Name.
In previous versions of AutoMapper, this same functionality also happened if you named the destination using _ as a splitting character, e.g. Account_Name. This no longer works by default.
There is a configuration setting, which you can set in the constructor of an individual mapping profile:
DestinationMemberNamingConvention = LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.Instance;

This brings back the previously supported behaviour.
However, we would have to include this in all mapping profiles as part of the upgrade, and we have nearly 500 of those, as we have one per output model. I'm obviously keen to reduce the amount of individual source changes as part of the upgrade, and was looking for a global solution.
I have tried applying the config setting on addition of AutoMapper to the Dependency Injected services on initialisation of the app, but it is just being ignored:
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => 
         {
             cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.Instance;
         }, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

When I debug the profile, in the constructor, the naming convention is still set to the PascalCase naming convention, until it hits my new line forcing it to the one I want.
Has anyone came across the same issue and managed to come up with a global solution to it?

This is not exactly reducing amount of source changes, but how about adding new abstract mapping profile where you set desired DestinationMemberNamingConvention, then use it as common inheritance base for all profiles where you need it. Use find and replace tool to minimize work needed and swap : Profile with : MyCustomProfile.

I don't why anybody would have 500 profiles. Then again, I've seen people have one map per profile :) But silliness aside, unless you have 500 modules in your app, there's no good reason for that.

@Lucian, we contain the mapping profile and the map(s) for a single POCO going to/from an EF Entity in the source file that defines the POCO.  It made perfect sense to us to keep everything relating to a POCO and its mapping in one place, and not to combine all the maps together in a monolithic profile file.

@Prolog, seen your actual answer, which I'll have a look at also, when I have a bit of time.  However, I had already gone for the concept of the abstract class and inheritance and using search and replace to make the changes.  We can do this in advance of the actual .Net 8 upgrade process, reliminating any individual source changes as part of that upgrade process.   Thanks a lot for your assistance.

That's a very poor use of profiles. Profiles are for logical grouping of maps and/or setting common things between maps. The way you use them is smth else altogether.

@Lucian, thanks for your input, however, given that we are where we are it does come across as critiquing our initial approach without offering anything to help.  We were new to AutoMapper when we first implemented it in this project and did the best we could.  As a profile was simply being used as the vehicle for picking up the map(s) contained within it by scanning the assembly it seemed a reasonable approach to us.  We obviously were not to know that changes to AutoMapper would render this approach difficult.  I do appreciate feedback but preferably feedback that helps us currently.

No, nothing changed here. What profiles are is well known and documented. You simply made a bad choice and now have to live with the consequences.

@Lucian, the previous behaviour where it supported underscore by default did indeed change.  However, as I say I do appreciate feedback, and hopefully someone embarking on using AutoMapper for the first time may find your comments helpful.

If reducing the amount of individual source changes as part of the upgrade is a priority for you, then you can register AutoMapper profiles on your own, manually, but preconfigured. This is a little bit of a hack, so there is a risk that it will break with future versions, but here we go.
Start with registering AutoMapper as usual. This will add AutoMapper core services and custom resolvers or converters. Since profiles will be added too, we need to get rid of them. Last Configure<>() call on services is the one adding maps, so let's remove that one. Since we removed the maps, we need to add them back. But in order to do that, we need to know what to add, so scan the assemblies looking for mapping profiles. With matching types obtained, use Activator.CreateInstance() to initialize every profile. Call the pre-configuration predicate and add back profiles, this time as already preconfigured instances.
public static void AddAutoMapperWithProfilePreconfiguration(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction,
    Action<Profile> preconfigureProfile,
    params Type[] profileAssemblyMarkerTypes)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(configAction, profileAssemblyMarkerTypes);

    // Remove mapping profiles configuration.
    var descriptorToRemove = services.Last(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(IConfigureOptions<MapperConfigurationExpression>));
    services.Remove(descriptorToRemove);

    // Find and initialize profiles.
    var profiles = ScanForProfiles(profileAssemblyMarkerTypes)
        .Select(type =>
        {
            var profile = (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            preconfigureProfile.Invoke(profile);

            return profile;
        });

    // Add mapping profiles back, this time as already preconfigured instances.
    services.Configure<MapperConfigurationExpression>(options => options.AddProfiles(profiles));
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> ScanForProfiles(params Type[] markerTypes)
{
    return markerTypes
        .Select(x => x.GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic && a != typeof(Profile).Assembly)
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
        .Where(x => typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract && !x.ContainsGenericParameters);
}

Usage:
services.AddAutoMapperWithProfilePreconfiguration(
    cfg => { },
    profile => profile.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention.Instance,
    profileAssemblyMarkerTypes: typeof(Program)); // Your types marking assembly to scan for profiles, resolvers, converters etc.

